# Iterate over a Map of Map in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a map of `Map<String, Map<String, Field_Utility.FieldData>>` called `objectsToFields`.
The `Field_Utility.FieldData` class looks like this:

```
public class Field_Utility {
//Other stuff
    class FieldData {
        public String fieldLabel {get;set;}
        public String fieldType {get;set;}
    }
}
```

This is a map of Object API Name to Map of Field API Name to Field Attributes.

The issue is the moment I drop this map on my VF page using `{!objectsToFields}` my page fails to load and throws the following error:
[image]

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!objectsToFields}" var="objects" >
        {!objects}
</apex:repeat>
```

Keep in mind I have a `{get;set;}` on the map. Now I know I can maintain a map of fields and a list of object names but I would like to know why this is failing.

**Edit**

Un-commenting the line `{!objectsToFields}` makes the error away. Also the page fails even if I create a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` and drop it on the page.

Comment: can you post VF code?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I have added the  VF code

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> objectsToFields {
    get {
        return new ServiceClass().getObjectsToFields();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why though.

Comment: It's hard to say why without seeing the original code that failed.

Comment: I have added the code in my question the only difference is `objectsToFields`  had a  `{get;set;}` @DavidReed